# Netsuite - Suitescript User Event Before Load - Get Sublist Value Join -> Set sublist value custom child record

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I've created a user event script before load (on Task form) which should insert the sublist values for multiple fields (custom sublist child record) on the task form. Sources by the "Transaction" field.

I would like to know how I can loop through the lines on the sales order and then create these lines in the custom child record.

This is what I have - This is working. But im missing the loop function and I do now understand it.

Would be pleased if someone can help:

update:

I found a way to loop the sublist.
But im not able to use the function "Commit Line" to set the next line on the custom sublist.
Does someone know how to do that?

```
/**

*@NApiVersion 2.x

*@NScriptType UserEventScript

*/

define(['N/record'],
function(record) {
function beforeLoad(context) {
if (context.type !== context.UserEventType.CREATE)
return;

        var newRecord = context.newRecord;

var objRecord = record.load({
    type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER, 
    id: context.newRecord.getValue({fieldId: 'transaction'}),
    isDynamic: true

  });

var objSublist = objRecord.getSublist({
   sublistId: 'item' 

});

  var numLines = objRecord.getLineCount({
    sublistId: 'item'
});

  for (var line = 0; line < numLines.length; line++)

  var objColumn = objSublist.getColumn({
   fieldId: 'item' 
});   

  var ObjField = objRecord.getSublistField({
    sublistId: 'item',
    fieldId: 'custcol12',
    line: line
  });

var sublistFieldValue = objRecord.getSublistValue({
    sublistId: 'item',
    fieldId: 'custcol12',
    line: line,
        });

      //SET Position#
   newRecord.setSublistValue({
          sublistId: 'recmachcustrecord250',
          fieldId: 'custrecord251',
          line: line,
          value: objRecord.getSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'custcol12',
            line: line})
});
        //SET Item
     newRecord.setSublistValue({
          sublistId: 'recmachcustrecord250',
          fieldId: 'custrecord252',
          line: line,
          value: objRecord.getSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'item',
            line: line})
});
      //SET Description
       newRecord.setSublistValue({
          sublistId: 'recmachcustrecord250',
          fieldId: 'custrecord253',
          line: line,
          value: objRecord.getSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'description',
            line: line})
});
    //SET QUANTITY
         newRecord.setSublistValue({
          sublistId: 'recmachcustrecord250',
          fieldId: 'custrecord257',
          line: line,
          value: objRecord.getSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'quantity',
            line: line})
});
  //SET INVENTORY DETAILS
           newRecord.setSublistValue({
          sublistId: 'recmachcustrecord250',
          fieldId: 'custrecord254',
          line: line,
          value: objRecord.getSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'inventorydetail',
            line: line})
});

    //SET Condition
           newRecord.setSublistValue({
          sublistId: 'recmachcustrecord250',
          fieldId: 'custrecord255',
          line: line,
          value: objRecord.getSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'custcol29',
            line: line})
});

}
return {
beforeLoad: beforeLoad,
};

});
```

Comment: update:

I found a way to loop the sublist.
But im not able to use the function "Commit Line" to set the next line on the custom sublist.
Does someone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you need to create custom record which is a child record on Task Record.

```
var objRecord = record.load({
    type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
    id: context.newRecord.getValue({ fieldId: 'transaction' }),
    isDynamic: true
});
var objSublist = objRecord.getSublist({
    sublistId: 'item'
});

var numLines = objRecord.getLineCount({
    sublistId: 'item'
});

for (var line = 0; line < numLines.length; line++) {

    //Get values from required fields of each line. 

   // create custom record for each SO line and make sure to add Parent (i.e. Task Record)

}
```

Let me know if this doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply
But the "create custom record for each SO line..." only happens after submit, right?
Because I would have to set the parent field value with the current transaction ID and this is not possible because its not created yet, right?

Comment: BTW: Maybe my idea is not good at all and you know a better way to proceed:

Explanation: We have 10# different Items on a Sales Order. 
1. I create a Task record and assign it to technician#1(T#1) for today.
2. I remove all items except Item#1 and Item#8 from the child record (on task)
3. I create a second Task and assign it to T#2 for tomorrow
4. I remove item#1 & item#8 because they are already assigned to technician#1
5. Both technicians will know which item# they have to repair

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. 
I forgot the {} loop area....

Here the final code

```
/**
*@NApiVersion 2.x
*@NScriptType UserEventScript
*/

define(['N/record'],
function(record) {
function beforeLoad(context) {
if (context.type !== context.UserEventType.CREATE)
return;
        var newRecord = context.newRecord;

var objRecord = record.load({
    type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER, 
    id: context.newRecord.getValue({fieldId: 'transaction'}),
    isDynamic: true

  });

var objSublist = objRecord.getSublist({
   sublistId: 'item' 

});


  var numLines = objRecord.getLineCount({
    sublistId: 'item'
});

        for (var i = 0; i < numLines; i++)  {

  var ObjField = objRecord.getSublistField({
    sublistId: 'item',
    fieldId: 'custcol12',
    line: i
  });

var sublistFieldValue = objRecord.getSublistValue({
    sublistId: 'item',
    fieldId: 'custcol12',
    line: i,
    value: true
        });


          //SET checkbox false
   newRecord.setSublistValue({
          sublistId: 'recmachcustrecord250',
          fieldId: 'custrecord265',
          line: i,
          value: false});

      //SET Position#
   newRecord.setSublistValue({
          sublistId: 'recmachcustrecord250',
          fieldId: 'custrecord251',
          line: i,
          value: objRecord.getSublistValue({sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'custcol12', line: i})
   });
        //SET Item
     newRecord.setSublistValue({
          sublistId: 'recmachcustrecord250',
          fieldId: 'custrecord252',
          line: i,
          value: objRecord.getSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'item',
            line: i,
            value: true})
});
      //SET Description
       newRecord.setSublistValue({
          sublistId: 'recmachcustrecord250',
          fieldId: 'custrecord253',
          line: i,
          value: objRecord.getSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'description',
            line: i,
            value: true})
});
    //SET QUANTITY
         newRecord.setSublistValue({
          sublistId: 'recmachcustrecord250',
          fieldId: 'custrecord257',
          line: i,
          value: objRecord.getSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'quantity',
            line: i,
            value: true})
});




          //GET INVENTORY DETAILS
          objRecord.selectLine({
                sublistId: 'item',
                line: i
            });

          try {

var subrec = objRecord.getCurrentSublistSubrecord({
                sublistId: 'item',
                fieldId: 'inventorydetail',
            });



  //SET INVENTORY DETAILS
           newRecord.setSublistValue({
          sublistId: 'recmachcustrecord250',
          fieldId: 'custrecord254',
          line: i,
          value: subrec.getSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',
            fieldId: 'issueinventorynumber',
            line: 0
          })})



}
catch(err) {

}


    //SET Condition
           newRecord.setSublistValue({
          sublistId: 'recmachcustrecord250',
          fieldId: 'custrecord255',
          line: i,
          value: objRecord.getSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'custcol29',
            line: i,
            value: true})

 });            
          //PLANNED CHECKBOX
                var planned = newRecord.getSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'recmachcustrecord250',
                fieldId: 'custrecord265',
                line: i}); 

          // REPAIR TIME /H
            newRecord.setSublistValue({
          sublistId: 'recmachcustrecord250',
          fieldId: 'custrecord256',
          line: i,
          value: objRecord.getSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'custcol37',
            line: i,
            value: true})
  });          

}
}

            function beforeSubmit(context) {
            if (context.type !== context.UserEventType.CREATE)
                return;
            var newRecord = context.newRecord;

                var numLines = newRecord.getLineCount({
                sublistId: 'recmachcustrecord250'});

              for(var line = numLines; line> -1; line--) {

              var planned = newRecord.getSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'recmachcustrecord250',
                fieldId: 'custrecord265',
                line: line}); 

               if (planned == false) {

                newRecord.removeLine({
                sublistId: 'recmachcustrecord250',
                line: line,
                ignoreRecalc: true})


              }
                }
        }


return {
beforeLoad: beforeLoad,
beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit,
};

});
```